# How to add horizontal line to SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

How do I add a horizontal (benchmark) line to an SSRS 2008 report?

Answer (score 1):

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790400/reporting-services-chart-hard-coded-series) guy hard codes the benchmark on every row.
- You may be able to use a [stripline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281363.aspx) to do it quickly.
- If you want a calculated series (eg. mean, median, etc) you can always right-click on the series and select "Add Calculated Series".