# How to display constant chart value?

Tags: reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add horizontal line to SSRS report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142265/how-to-add-horizontal-line-to-ssrs-report)

I am developing a SSRS 2008 report and I'm trying to get a horizontal line to appear on my chart.  I am able to get this line to appear by the expression "=0.90".  However, if I only have one value along the X-axis, then this line does not appear.  How can I get it to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Splitline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142265/how-to-add-horizontal-line-to-ssrs-report)